# How to get the "lastEventId" from fastapi websocket answer?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, fastapi

I want to get the "lastEventId" from a websocket answer from fastapi. When inspecting the code in the browser I see that the returned object has a field "lastEventId" but unfortunately it is empty. Does anyone know how to get this variable?
(The code is derived from the example code on fastapi webpage and should run under the premise `pip install websocket`)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
import re
from icecream import ic

app = FastAPI()


html = """

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Form</h1>
        <form name="testform" action="" onsubmit="" onKeyUp="sendMessage(event)">
            <input type="text" id="messageText" autocomplete="off" placeholder="text" />
            <span id="texterror"></span>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                console.log("answer from fastapi websocket: ",event)
                //the following variable is always null
                var field = document.getElementById(event.lastEventId)
                console.log("the find the last element: ", field);
            };

            function sendMessage(event) {

                // event.srcElemt.id because the final form shall have more inputs
                var input = document.getElementById(event.srcElement.id);
                console.log("value of following element to fastapi websocket: ",input);
                ws.send(input.value)
            }

        </script>

    </body>

</html>

"""



@app.get("/")

async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(html)



@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        ic(websocket.__dict__)
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        print('"'+data+'"')
        await websocket.send_text(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mistaking WebSockets with Server-Sent-Events

Server-Sent Events vs. WebSockets
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-introduction-differences

> Server-Sent Events have a variety of features that WebSockets lack by design such as automatic reconnection, event IDs, and the ability to send arbitrary events.

A similar question was asked in [Is there any ID for data chunks in WebSocket like lastEventId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330898/is-there-any-id-for-data-chunks-in-websocket-like-lasteventid/67375755#67375755)

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: I did include the essential parts of the answer here, and I referenced another StackOverflow question with more information.