# Is there any ID for data chunks in WebSocket like lastEventId?

Tags: javascript, websocket, lighttpd

I am sending an image from server on a button press event in browser (client) using WebSockets. The image data received in onmessage() method of WebSocket API is in a Blob structure and in several chunks. The issue is on multiple button press events in a short period, the chunks being received are **out of order**.

Is there any **identifier that I can use to differentiate the chunks** on browser side? There is a field in WebSocket event "lastEventId", but it is always empty.

```
socket.onmessage = (event) =>
{
    console.log(event.data); // Chunked Blob data
    console.log(event.lastEventId); // Always empty
    // Process data
}
```

OR

The server is a **lighttpd server** so is there any configuration of lighttpd required to enable some kind of ID for the data chunks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mistaking WebSockets with Server-Sent-Events

Server-Sent Events vs. WebSockets
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-introduction-differences

> Server-Sent Events have a variety of features that WebSockets lack by design such as automatic reconnection, event IDs, and the ability to send arbitrary events.

If your server-side script is the websocket endpoint, then you can include an id with your Server-Sent Events response, and send it properly framed in websocket frames.

If you are using lighttpd [mod_wstunnel](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModWSTunnel) to perform generic websocket framing, then you will have to appropriately structure the blob data in your script, and then the client will have to reconstruct the blob, potentially from multiple websocket frames.  lighttpd mod_wstunnel works quite well with a JSON payload, so you might consider sending (small!) images as part of base64-encoded JSON.  This is by no means the only way to do this.

Edit: further doc on [Server-Sent Events](https://javascript.info/server-sent-events)

Comment: Yes, I am using mod_wstunnel. I am reconstructing the image from blob data and it does work in normal circumstances. Only when multiple events are generated in a very short period and the server sends the images rapidly, the frames I am getting on client side are out of order. Is there any way to introduce a ID through mod_wstunnel configuration then?

Comment: No. Once again, you seem to be confused about the difference between WebSockets and Server-Side-Events.  Please reference the links I provided.

Comment: I will argue this answer is incorrect. ws onmessage event does have lastEventId.